# Indexes order in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, matrix

I'm basically coding some sort of table where for column tags I have some *numbers* and for row tags I have some strings which contain such numbers separated by commas.

I'm taking all the row tags from a **TString** named `minterms_essentials` and the column tags from one named `minterms`.

First I must *tag* the created 2 dimensions array. And then, if any string from the rows contains certain letter, I must place an `'x'` in the proper column.

I've wrote this Delphi code but I'm getting access violation so far...

SetLength(tabla, minterms_essentials.Count+1,minterms.Count+1);

```
for i := 0 to minterms.Count-1 do
begin
  tabla[0,i+1] := IntToStr(BinToInt(minterms[i]));
end;

for i := 0 to minterms_essentials.Count-1 do
begin
  tabla[i+1,0] := minterms_essentials[i];
end;

for i := 1 to minterms_essentials.Count-1 do
begin
for g := 1 to minterms.Count-1 do
  begin
    ss := tabla[g,0].Split([',']);
    for s in ss do
      begin
        if s = tabla[0,g] then
          begin
            tabla[g,i] := 'x';
          end;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Is there any better and correct way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this:

first dimension is defined by **minterms_essentials**

```
SetLength(tabla, minterms_essentials.Count+1,minterms.Count+1);
```

but here you are using **minterms** to index first dimension of array:

```
for g := 1 to minterms.Count-1 do
  begin
    ss := tabla[g,0].Split([',']);
```

**P.S**. Have you still not turned on range check?

Comment: additionally you should change the following line  tabla[g,i] := 'x'; to  tabla[i,g] := 'x';